# special character in smb field in Printer dialog

Tags: kubuntu, printing, special-characters

I am trying to add a Windows printer via SAMBA from the New Printer dialog in Kubuntu 12.04. The smb:// field doesn't allow me to put special character or blank spaces, except for the underscore (see screenshot). In particular, the url I am trying to add (it was given to me by IT people in my university) contains a "%20", which, I assume, should be interpreted as a space.

> Is this normal? Can smb urls contain special characters? Why doesn't this dialog allow me to do that?

[image]

Comment: I don't have direct answer for the question. But you can try using IP address directly.

Comment: @JohnSiu: well, I have an IP address for the server, but not for the name of the printer and 'Browse' doesn't help, somehow it gets stuck.

Comment: (1) Use your file manager, go to network location using the server IP address, may be you can get an alternative printer name (without space and special characters). (2) Does the printer name (provided to you) portion contain space too?

Comment: @JohnSiu: I tried that too. For some reasons, I get a timeout on the server when I try to browse.

Comment: Do you know if it is a windows server or a samba server? If samba, that means linux, we maybe able to cheat a little and use ipp instead.

Comment: @JohnSiu: thanks for the help! I found a workaround that works. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug and the workaround is explained here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdeadmin/+bug/909769

Comment: ooo, I thought it is not accepting the % char, lol. Nice you found it :) KDE has been around for years. I am surprise they have a bug like that lasting that long.

Comment: @JohnSiu: indeed, it's not accepting the % char in that mask, but it is if you add a printer from the Other dialog, not the Samba one.